# Unable to use github library in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I want to use [this library](https://github.com/Diolor/Swipecards) in a project in Android Studio, so as mentioned in read me, I created new project in the Android Studio and added dependencies in build.gradle file inside the app folder as:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mycompany.swipe_instagram"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
       release {
           minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
    }
}

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
} 

dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
   compile 'com.lorentzos.swipecards:library:1.0.8@aar'
}
```

Then when I sync I started getting this error as:

[image: Failed to find file]

I have Searched on the google and stack overflow but can't find any appropriate solution.

Comment: Try it without `@aar`

Comment: @MuratK.: Not working without  `@aar` also

Comment: Preferred way to reference the library is without "@aar" but either should work.

Comment: Ensure you're in online mode.

Comment: @EugenPechanec: yes, I have internet connectivity...

Comment: That's nice, now check that gradle knows that. File -> Settings -> Gradle -> Offline work -- is supposed to be unticked. Then clean & build the project.

Comment: @EugenPechanec: Thanks, Noweverything is working fine but offline work is unticked, So if this is unticked then is there in future big issue

Answer (score 0):

I used your "build.gradle" file and it is working fine for me (both with and without "aar").  Could be something wrong with the cache.  Try "File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart").  Another way to generate more error message detail is to try building the module from the command line and getting verbose output

```
gradle -info compileDebugSources
```

You'll get lots of output which should give you a hint as to what's going wrong